# android studio - making a navigation drawer project as a template

Tags: android, android-studio, navigation-drawer

After fighting android studio and struggling with endless how-to's I finally managed to make a working drawer navigation app and actually, that's all it does at the moment.

I want to make this project as a template for my real apps so whenever I'll start a new app, this will be my base line - how can I do it?

Comment: I just copy it to a new directory, and delete the `.iml` files and `.idea/` directories. Then I import it into Android Studio, giving me a new project. I can then refactor and edit the copy from there. Is that what you mean, or did you have something else in mind?

Comment: Please add your comment as an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to clone a project to create a new project, copy the original project to a new directory, named whatever you want the new project to be named. Delete the `.iml` and `.idea/` directory in your copy. Then, import the copy into Android Studio as a non-Android Studio project. Android Studio will create a fresh `.iml` file and `.idea/` directory for you. From there, you can refactor and otherwise modify the copy as you see fit.